# Anchor/Image That Has Different Image For Hover and Click States

Tags: jquery, html, css

A little confused on how to do this since I haven't done this before, but I have 3 images:

One Image as the default state: 1.png, 2nd Image as the hover state: 2.png, and the 3rd image for when the link/image is clicked: 3.png

How would I setup these 3 images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through css classes.
For instance:

```
<div class="image"></div>

<style type="text/css">   
    .image {
      background: url(1.png) no-repeat top left;
    }
    .image:hover {
      background: url(2.png) no-repeat top left;
    }
    .image:active {
      background: url(3.png) no-repeat top left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, glad to meet nice people over here ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can set them as three different images and control them via css as described bellow.

```
#my-image {
    background: url("/1.png");
}

#my-image:hover {
    background: url("/2.png");
}

#my-image:active {
    background: url("/3.png");
}
```

**But a commonly used technic is css-sprites.** You combine those 3 images into a single image. Say each image image is 100x100px so you make an image that's 100x300px. And then you control the `background-position`. This eliminates the problem of lack of responsiveness for the user and is easier on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Above two solutions would not work properly because for the a:active the image will not permantly change.You have to use jquery for this and everyone do this also:

```
                <html>
                 <head>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#my_link").hover(function(){
                          $(this).removeClass("class_1").addClass("class_2");
                          },function(){
                          $(this).removeClass("class_2").addClass("class_1"); 
                       });

                   $("#my_link").click(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass("class_1").addClass("class_3");
                   });
              });

             </script> 
             <style type="text/css">
                .class_1{background: url("/1.png") no-repeat top left;}
                .class_2{background: url("/2.png") no-repeat top left;}
                .class_3{background: url("/3.png") no-repeat top left;}  
             </style>
         </head>
         <body>
              <a id="my_link" class="class_1" href="#" >Click here</a>
         </body>
       </html>
```

This works fine for me.I hope it will work !